# drupal 7 feed importer doesn't make line breaks paragraphs

Tags: import, drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-feeds

I have a D7 site with CKEDitor installed, a Text Format that allows `<p>` tags and has "convert line breaks into HTML" selected, and I'm importing a csv utf-8 file made from an excel speadsheet that had some cells with several "paragraphs" in them. I guess for semantic sake, these are just line breaks. I can see the text broken up into what look like paragraphs in the csv.

I want this text to be paragraphs, though. When I do the import and look at a node I created, it looks fine and I can inspect the text and see that `<p>`'s wrap the paragraphs. But if I go to edit the node, in my CKEditor I see that all the paragraph text in now one big paragraph. How can I get all the paragraphs to show?

Answer (score 0):

In feed importer module you have the option to change the filtered html type.It filters all html tags inside the content.

Comment: If you're referring to the text format in the node processor settings, I have it set to Filtered HTML. Is that what you mean? If so, it must be something other than that then.